# Excel slow with other spreadsheets open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple VBA code running in workbook A that is rather slow when another specific workbook B is open. I don't have access to any macros inside workbook B, so I can't know for sure if anything wierd is happening there.

I've looked around and came with this minimal code condensing the typical solutions I've found in stackoverflow and many Excel specific sites, but it still takes a long time to run.

```
' Code in workbook A
Sub slow_simple_macro()
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
End with

Workbooks("workbookA.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Slow" ' This line takes about half a second to run when workbook B is open

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
End with
End Sub
```

I'm guessing that disabling events is not enough to prevent something inside workbook B from running. Are there any other Application flags I can setup to make it run faster? Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you need Workbook B open? Otherwise, include a test to see if open and close w/wout save changes.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Closing it could work with user input, but I'd like to find a solution that doesn't rely on that.

Comment: What are the features of Workbook B that you might think could be a problem? E.g. lots of conditional formatting, large size, lots of calcs..... Do you make an changes to B whilst working with A?

Comment: Workbook B is a legacy monster I can't get rid off (I wish I could though). It does all sorts of things such as validation over the network, conditional formating and so on. I will need to read from it when starting my process, but not modify it while running macros in Workbook A. The main issue is that even though I'm not touching B when running the macro in the example, it still is much slower just by B being open. It is worth saying that disabling events and so on helped with other parts of the main macro in A being slow, but writing to A with B open is still slow.

Comment: What are you opportunities for streamlining B? E.g removing unnecessary conditional formatting, under objects such as sheets not used, formulas etc, saving as .xlsb if appropriate......

Comment: Zero opportunities. This workbook is provided by another area and I have to live with that. Is it possible reading from a workbook without opening it? I have a macro that opens a workbook, reads from it and closes it in the background. If I could read it without triggering all the macros it could be a way.

Comment: Higher spec machine you can try running on?

Comment: This tool will be sent to end users on low-end notebooks, so I'll have to find a way around it

Answer (score 0):

You can see while disabling some functions of excel like calculation mode, screenupdates,status bar would impact on application of Excel because "Excel is the one of The object model that is a large hierarchy of all the objects used in VBA" (Source:www.globaliconnect.com).

So if you want run by turn off application functions , you should be wait till you set back to its original or else same problem would happen.

Better simplify code as possible unless if its required

```
Sub slow_simple_macro()
Workbooks("workbookA.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Slow" 
End Sub
```

Hope you find it as helpful. Have a good day.